# Скорость работы запросов FireBird

Tags: sql, firebird

Добрый день.

Пытаюсь разработать базу данных для своего приложения в Firebird, при этом хочется реализовать в ней некоторый механизм управления пользователями и их правами (встроенный в саму БД слишком комплексный для моих задач).

Суть проста: все действия приложения с данными в таблицах выполняются через хранимые процедуры (таблиц планируется всего 5-6), при этом все пользователи приложения (далее просто пользователи) работают с БД через одного общего пользователя БД, у которого есть права на Execute всех SP и больше ни на что (все остальные необходимые права даются самим процедурам).

При этом каждая SP, при обращении к ней, проверяет текущего пользователя через запрос вида

```
  select s.user_id from session
  left join users u on u.user_id = s.user_id
  where (s.session_id = rdb$get_context('USER_SESSION', 'SESSION_ID'))
    and (u.enabled = 1)
  into :uid;
```

**Вопрос №1**: насколько критична с точки зрения времени выполнения проверка состояния пользователя при каждом обращении к SP?

Или, возможно, стоит упростить до

```
select user_id from session
where session_id = rdb$get_context('USER_SESSION', 'SESSION_ID')
into :uid
```

, а включен пользователь или нет, проверять только в USER_LOGIN?..

**Вопрос №2**: с точки зрения удобства и красоты хочется вообще вынести этот код (первый вариант) в отдельную SP, чтобы не дублировать его в начале каждой другой SP, что-то вроде:

```
execute procedure get_currentuser returning_values :uid;
```

, но не смог найти подробной информации о вложенных вызовах процедур в Firebird. Хотелось бы узнать, насколько правильно так делать и насколько быстро или медленно это работает?

P.S: Примерный вид таблиц SESSION и USERS можно [увидеть тут](https://www.dropbox.com/s/va3dhmlotseitcs/fbase.png?dl=0).

Comment: По поводу скорости работы: для того чтобы увидеть насколько критична с точки зрения времени выполнения, необходимо посмотреть анализ плана,  где вам покажут сколько чего и за сколько времени вы его выполняете! Думаю, в вашем случае это не критично, хотя это очень зависит от данных!
По поводу второго вопроса информацию искали плохо, а вот ваш подход на счет процедур. лучше занести во View

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Вопрос №1**. Не критично.
Но если упрощать, то до

```
uid = rdb$get_context('USER_SESSION', 'USER_ID')
```

а состояние пользователя проверять и выставлять сессионную переменную в триггере на `ON CONNECT` или `ON TRANSACTION START`

**Вопрос №2**. Вложенные хранимки прекрасно работают. Лучше использовать их, чем копипастить код.

PS у нас в проекте используется аналог вашей `get_currentuser`.
Она проверяет сессионную переменную, если та заполнена - то возвращает ее, если нет, то делает запрос и записывает результат в сессионную переменную.

Comment: Спасибо. Упрощение до `uid = rdb$get_context('USER_SESSION', 'USER_ID')` не подходит, потому что тогда можно тупо выполнить `rdb$set_context('USER_SESSION', 'USER_ID', 2)`, например, и залогиниться как какой-то пользователь без авторизации. А права на rdb$set_context не устанавливаются.